# How can I use integrated Windows Authentication when debugging locally with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, configuration, windows-authentication, cassini

I'm using RESTful WCF services to serve data to a client. The application hosting the services requires integrated Windows Authentication on the server, making testing locally in Cassini quite difficult. I use the following behavior configuration for my service, which works great when deployed to IIS with Integrated Security turned on.

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="InstaCheckServiceWebHttpBinding">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

But with this configuration the app throws the following error when I try to call the web services when debugging locally in Visual Studio.

*Security settings for this service require 'Windows' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service*

Is there a way to include integrated Windows Auth when using Visual Studio's built-in web server, or some other workaround to this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854395/help-how-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-asp-net-development-server)

TLDR version: I don't think Cassini is ideal for WCF if you want to debug security settings

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's a bit discouraging that I can't properly debug WCF security issues without going outside of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

Change your project to use IIS instead of Cassini.

1. Right Click your Project and select
   Properties then the Web tab.
2. Select Use Local IIS Web Server and
       click the Create Virtual Directory
       button to have Visual Studio setup
       the site in IIS for you.
3. Go to IIS MMC snap-in and configure
       the appropriate settings for Windows
       Authentication.

Now when you run you project it will use IIS instead of Cassini.

Comment: Yes, that's what I normally do. But I don't have IIS installed on my machine and am not sure the admins will allow it.