# Where are my Visual Studio programs/applications/websites hosted by default?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, iis, hosting

Where are my Visual Studio programs/applications/websites hosted by default (/during debugging)?
I mean, when I run my project in studio or just do a right click and 'view in browser' on a page... where is the page hosted?

Someone at work mentioned 'Visual Studio server'. And also that we can direct the studio to use the local IIS.

Can anyone shed more light on this, or point to a blog/article where I can find more info?

Thanks!

Edit: I am asking this question because my WCF service authentication settings behave differently (service doesn't work) when I run the service on my local vs. on the dev server. And I am trying to figure where to look for those local settings.

Edit: I am using VS 2010, and have IIS 7 installed on my local.

Comment: I would think that it uses the IIS setup on your local machine by default...

Comment: I thought so too, but I think it is not so. Any changes on the local IIS reflect only if I explicitly deploy my application onto it. Not when I run it on VS.

Comment: As @Brian Mains has answered, Visual Studio 2010 uses Visual Studio Development Server aka Cassini as the default web server. What settings would you like to change?

Comment: I need to set the authentication to 'Windows'. I can do that on my Local IIS and Dev-Server IIS, and my service works fine. I want to be able to do it on Cassini, so that I don't have to change my config file while working on local. This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854395/help-how-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-asp-net-development-server  seems to suggest Cassini is very limited and it cant be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which version you have installed.  In VS 2012, if you setup a web app, it uses IIS express by default, which gives it a `http://localhost:<port>` (such as 2122 or something like that).  You have to add it as a virtual directory for it to be hosted under IIS.  You can very easily do that from your project's properties, under Web tab.

Previous versions used Cassini as the local web server.

Comment: I have VS2010, and IIS 7 on Local. I am able to deploy to local IIS and change the IIS settings to make my service work. But my problem is which is the web-server for for debugging mode. I assume your answer is Cassini - How can I access its settings?

Comment: OK, so your service is an IIS virtual directory, standalone from a web project?

Comment: In IIS, you should be able to attach to the IIS process hosting the service using this approach: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3.aspx.  You attach to the W3WP.exe process (the IIS worker process)

Comment: Thanks Brian. I took the liberty to edit and add the original server name in your answer. So, as I mentioned in the other comment, I need to change the authentication settings on Cassini. Do you still think 'attaching to Running process' is the way to go?